# What is the current king of the hill for rich text textarea editors?

Tags: javascript, html, editor, richtextbox, textarea

Just wondering: what is the current king of the hill for rich text textarea editors?

Last time i checked (years ago) it was TinyMCE, is there a better option now?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i prefer [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/). it has less bug than tinymce and it has more FREE plugins

Comment: You gotta be kidding me :-o ckeditor is so damn slow. It's certainly not something you want to use for internet application.

Comment: hard to call this the "answer" when the question is so subjective.

Answer (score 1):

I like [tinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com) as it is very simple and very simple to implement.  It also allows you clean up the Word guff on paste automatically which is very handy

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if it is possible to be definitive here, but [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) (formerly fckeditor) is really solid.

If you add the search terms of ckeditor and fckeditor together, it might be overtaking TinyMCE...

http://www.google.com/trends?q=tinymce,fckeditor,ckeditor

Comment: when you say formally, do you mean formerly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what server side platform you're using, but I've always been a big fan of the [Telerik](http://telerik.com) [RadEditor](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/editor.aspx) for ASP.NET AJAX.  There's also one for [MVC](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/editor.aspx).

The ASP.NET AJAX version is far from free, but it's by far the most powerful and diverse wysiwyg editor I've ever seen.  Awesome file browser, fantastic skins, customizable buttons, everything you would expect from a rich text editor.

EDIT:
I see that you actually asked for a textarea editor, which probably means that you're looking for something exclusively JavaScript.  Sorry, this tool doesn't do that.  It's actually an ASP.NET Control.